# send html email with embedded images

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have scheduled a Jupyter notebook to run periodically using jupyter nbconvert utility. It create a single html file that contains embedded images.  I would like to send an email with the html file's **content** in the mail body (rather than as an attachment).  How do I do that?

I'm using Linux. I don't mind using any command line utilities or even a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can use Thunderbird's [command line interface](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29) for this. (Specifically, the HTML file would go under the "message" argument.)